# How do I run a Makefile that was distributed with a Java library?

Tags: java, makefile

I downloaded a Java library with a file titled Makefile, but I do not know what to run it with. It has no extension, and this is the text that appears when I open it in TextEdit:

```
all: BigDecimalMath.jar Wigner3jGUI.jar html

html:
    javadoc -sourcepath . -private -d html org.nevec.rjm

BigDecimalMath.jar:
    javac org/nevec/rjm/*.java
    jar cf $@ org

Wigner3jGUI.jar:
    javac org/nevec/rjm/*.java
    jar cmf Wigner3jGUI.mf $@ org/nevec/rjm/*.class

distclean:
    rm -rf html *.jar org/nevec/rjm/*.class
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to run this file (By the way, I have a Mac running Mavericks if that matters at all)

Comment: Why did this question get so many downvotes? To me, this is a legit question...

Answer (score 0):

try two commands

```
make
java -jar Wigner3jGUI.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles are similar to ant files and are run by the `make` program.  I have not seen make used to build jars (usually c/c++).  However, it looks like it will build the jars.  The all target should build the jars, which can then be run by the java command.

Comment: When I do make and then drag in the file, the terminal says Nothing to be done for `/Users/myname/Downloads/arXiv-0908-3030v2/anc.jar/Makefile'.

Comment: Some things to check: Does the jar files already exist? Does the ./org/.... structure exist? Did you unpack the download? Also try supplying the all target to make.

Comment: I do not use the Mac operating system, so I am not sure what the current directory will be when you drag the makefile into the make program icon.  The makefile appears to expect all the resources to be in the current directory.  The drag action may be breaking this.  Can you run from the command line?